# creating modified version of an official Eclipse distribution

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need to create a modified distribution (package?) of *Eclipse 4.2 for Java EE Developers*. It's going to be distributed to the team with all required plugins (should be ready for development out-of-the-box).
I'm trying to use Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers to achieve this, but the documentation is mostly outdated and doesn't help much.

I fetched the original projects for Eclipse packages from http://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages. I'm using `org.eclipse.epp.packages.jee` and `org.eclipse.epp.packages.jee.feature`. I can launch it and I can export it, but there are two problems I've encountered:

1. The launched and exported packages differ from the original *Eclipse for Java EE Developers* (contains unneeded plugins - e.g. for RCP, and also the hierarchy in *Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation details* is a little different).
2. I can't find any way to automatically resolve dependencies (the product is based on features) - in order to export the package without any "missing import/package" errors I had to add an existing unzipped *Eclipse for Java EE Developers* package in *Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform*.

Is there any way to build the package without differences from the original version? And what is the proper way of handling missing plugins/dependencies?

Comment: Is it you want to start with Eclipse for Java EE developers and then add some features?  Which ones do you want above and beyond what's there?

Comment: I've already abandoned the idea, because I couldn't spend more time on it. But that's exactly what I wanted to do. Take Eclipse JEE and add at least Subversive (with SVNKit connector), m2e, WorkspaceMechanic to the installation, but in a way that it would be updatable. I've tried RCP, p2 and Tycho. Each one had it's problems, so I gave up. At least for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier:

1. Download the Eclipse 4.2 Java EE package
2. Download the RCP Edition.

Call the p2 director of your RCP edition to install bundles from content-repositories into your JEE packages. For an example, see http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_director_application/Examples/Install_into_eclipse_using_SDKProfile

Comment: It doesn't really work well. Installation behaves like everything is correct, but all I've got was either all update sites removed (and installed plugin was not listed in features), or even no reaction to installation (nothing in plugins and features in _Installation details_, but jars were present in the `plugins/` directory).